# Append a new character to a string using pass by referencce

Tags: python, arrays, string, pass-by-reference

I am trying to add a string to another string by passing the value to another function but does not append.

```
def test2(s1,s2):
   s1 = s1+s2
   s1 = 'z'+s1
   return len(s1)

def test(s1,s2):
   i = test2(s1,s2)
   print(i)
   print(s1)

String1 = raw_input()
String2 = raw_input()

test(String1, String2)
```

input  - `a,b`
output expected - `3, zab`

But I am getting  - `3,a`

Comment: string objects are immutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as "pass by reference" in Python and string objects are immutable so you cannot modify the string passed to a function.

Comment: How can I perform the same operation in other way?

Comment: @Fox you cannot. Return the new string if you really need that.

Comment: k .. Thanks .. Figured out a way .. using class

Answer (score -2):

If you really want to work on an object thats passed by reference you can use a list. A minor modification of your program then becomes

```
def test2(s1,s2):
   s1.extend(s2)
   s1.insert(0,'z')
   return len(s1)

def test(s1,s2):
   i = test2(s1,s2)
   print(i)
   print(s1)

String1 = list(raw_input())
String2 = list(raw_input())

test(String1, String2)
```

Comment: Turning a string into a list of characters so you can manipulate it seems really ugly.

Comment: I agree - its not an elegant solution at all. However, the point was to highlight that passing by reference isn't the problem in the question that was asked - its the immutability of the datatype that is.

Comment: And I need to add'z' to the begining of the string not the end

Comment: Fox, sorry about that - oversight, it should be insert(0,'z') instead. updated.